# How to limit bandwidth from inside OpenVZ container without tc?

Tags: bandwidth, openvz

As the title says I would like to know if it is possible to limit bandwidth (download and upload) of OpenVZ container (from inside it) without use of `tc` or any additional kernel driver (VPS provider does not support it).

I can enable TUN/TAP interfaces in the VPS, can it be used to locally shape the traffic in both directions (total bandwidth is limited, I cannot simply do the shaping somewhere else)? I looked at OpenVPN, but it seems that only one direction can be shaped and also I'm not entirely sure how to setup routing to make it working.

PS: For my purpose I cannot use `trickle` or proxy. The application I want to be limited doesn't allow setting proxy and runs in multiple processes so `trickle` can't handle it.